# How to test a Vue plugin's functions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

So I have the following class of wrapper functions called `cookie.js`:

```
export default {

  Vue: null,

  set (name, value, options) {
    const defaultOptions = {
      sameSite: 'lax',
      secure: true
    };

    this.Vue.$cookies.set(name, value, Object.assign(defaultOptions, options));
  },

  get (name) {
    return this.Vue.$cookies.get(name);
  },

  remove (name) {
    this.Vue.$cookies.remove(name);
  }
};
```

And I install this plugin like this:

```
import cookiePlugin from 'plugins/cookie';

Vue.use({
  install (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$cookie = function () {
      return Object.assign(cookiePlugin, {
        options,
        Vue: this
      });
    };
  }
});
```

I want to create a test class for the `set`, `get`, and `remove` methods in `cookie.js`.

From looking at various docs and questions on this site, I think the beginning of the setup for the test class is roughly something like:

```
import Cookie from './cookie';
import { createLocalVue } from 'vue-test-utils'

it('sets up a cookie with correct options', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(Cookie);

  // here is where I'm unsure how proceed/call the methods I want to test. 

});
```

I was thinking you do something like `localVue.prototype.$cookie().set(...)` from here for example, but I don't think thats right since I always get undefined property errors. Other examples seem to show things like `localVue.prototype.$plugin` where `$plugin` is a specific method, not like a class of methods like I have.

Any suggestions?